# Having trouble shrinking the width of image in Carousel Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, carousel

I'm having trouble shrinking the width of images in Carousel Bootstrap while having a fixed navigation bar for each image. Whenever I adjust the size of each image in Carousel, the position of Carousel control previous/next icon changes as well.

For instance, I want each image to have an image width size of this, where I can see both the Carousel control/previous/next icon:

[image]

But for some reason, other photos are shown enlarged, which makes the image stretched out like this:

[image]

I have tried adjusting the "d-block w-___" and adjusted from CSS, but nothing works fine..

Here is my HTML:

```
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-80" src="Photos/mcdonalds.JPG" alt="First slide">
            <p>October, 2020. McDonald's at Main St., BC.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="Photos/statute.JPG" alt="Second slide">
            <p>June, 2020. Kelowna, BC.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-70" src="Photos/trees.JPG" alt="Third slide">
            <p>November, 2020. Bute St., BC.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="Photos/wall.JPG" alt="Forth slide slide">
            <p>October, 2019.Su-Won, Korea.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.carousel-inner img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60vw;
    max-height: 530px;

}

.carousel-inner p {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Hi can you post more code of the actual carousel?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a max-width property in your code as follows,

```
.carousel-inner img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /* width: 60vw; */
    max-height: 530px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```